# What is the difference between these verilog codes?

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm was following a tutorial to blink a led in my fpga.
These are the codes presented :

1)

```
module LED (    
    input      [17:0] SW,
    output reg [17:0] LEDR
);    
    assign led = switch;
endmodule
```

2) --------

```
module LED (    
    input [17:0] SW,
    output reg [17:0] LEDR
);
    always @(*)
        led = switch;
endmodule
```

3) ---------

```
module LED (        
    input CLOCK_50,
    input [17:0] SW,
    output reg [17:0] LEDR
);

    always @(posedge CLOCK_50)
        LEDR = SW;
endmodule
```

Comment: What is the question? Also, please format the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example uses continuous assignment to set the value of **led** to the value of **switch**. It's like connecting **led** and **switch** directly with a wire. Whenever **switch** changes, **led** also changes.

Your second example does the same thing but uses an **always** block. **always** blocks have a sensitivity list, which contains signals that will trigger the block to run. In this case, it's *****, meaning that it triggers any time any of the signals in the blocks change. I believe this is identical to your first example.

Your third example uses sequential logic to set **LEDR** to **SW**. In this case, the **always** block triggers only when the **CLOCK_50** signal goes high from a non-high state. If **CLOCK_50** never rises, **LEDR** is never set to any value.

By the way, I don't think your first or second examples are synthesizable. I think **led** and **switch** should be **LEDR** and **SW**.

These articles give a better description of the concepts in your examples:

Assignments : http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00005.htm

Always Blocks: http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog_one_day3.html

Comment: Thanks !! You are correct, LED and switch should be LEFT and SW. So all this code do the same thing? but what is the recommended way? The third?

Comment: LED should be LEDR****

Comment: @Bruno I don't think there's a "recommended" way; it depends on what your goal is. You'll have to research combinational logic and sequential logic in order to see which one is a better fit for your needs. If you just want to set the LEDs, an assignment is fine.

Comment: @Bruno No they are not all the same.  The first two are the same.  If you are doing something this simple you would use the first.  If it gets much more complicated, then the always block will become useful.  The third case is different.  It is the logic for a flip-flop between SW and LEDR, so in this case SW and LEDR will not be the same at all times.  The value is just copied at each clock.